# Not able to select Customer community user in lookup on custom object

Tags: community, lookup, customer-community

I have a custom object where I have a look up of User. When I'm trying to select the lookup customer community user it doesn't show user there.

Comment: I also have this problem. Can anyone advise? It works in Lightning but not in Salesforce classic.